# C# - middleware that adds field value to controller argument if argument inherits from interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2, middleware

I could use some advise or pointers. My middleware knowledge is failing me today.

Suppose I have a controller endpoint that looks like this

```
public int Create([FromBody] InputDto InputDto)
```

And that InputDto looks like this

```
public class InputDto : IHasSpecialThingy
{
    public SpecialThingy SpecialThingy { get; set; }
    // Plus some other cool fields
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is some intermediate middleware that checks when an object inherits from "IHasSpecialThingy", add SpecialThingy onto it..

I have tried creating my own IModelBinder, with little success.

Middleware is unfortunately not my strong suit. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for any help.

***EDIT***

I started with a IActionFilter with a custom implementation. It should be good. Need to still figure out some Dependency injection for it. I will post an answer when I have cleaned it up a lot. Will still keep it open for quite some while as someone might have a better solution me.

Comment: is a type check no good?

Comment: I think the IModelBinder Registration does not check for inherited types, unless I am doing something wrong. Ideally, It would be great to have a generic solution such that anything that inherits from IHasSpecailThingy can easily be populated by that middleware

Comment: Btw. Anyone know how to implement Dependency injection on a custom IActionFilter instead of an ActionFilterAttribute ?

Comment: Please see my answer if you are still wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem. Please see the code below.

```
public class SpecialThingyFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public bool AllowMultiple { get; }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        var commandsWithSpecialThingy = actionContext.ActionArguments
            .Where(x => x.Value != null && x.Value.GetType().GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IHasSpecialThingy)))
            .Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

        if (!commandsWithSpecialThingy.Any())
        {
            return await continuation.Invoke();
        }

        foreach (var dto in commandsWithSpecialThingy)
        {
            //Do your magic stuffs here
            ((IHasSpecialThingy)dto).specialThingy = // Something special
        }

        return await continuation.Invoke();
    }
}
```

You can also use DI in the action filter if your DI container is setup correctly.

```
var specialtyService = actionContext.ControllerContext
      .Configuration.DependencyResolver
      .GetService(typeof(ISpecialtyService)) as ISpecialtyService;
```

Please let me know if you have any questions or if you come across his and need some help with a similar issue.